# determine box size needed

Tags: math, bin-packing

I am trying to calculate the size a big rectangle needed to pack smaller ones.he smaller rectangle have fixed know size and the big rectangle have a fixed width.

In the image, 6 rectangle can fit the big rectangle in which the initial `w` and height `h1` . Now if give more small rectangle, how do i determine the height h2, h3, h4.

i initially went the bin packing route, but this didnt really help as it mainly focused on how many smaller rectangle can fit a big one, but i need instead how much size (height) is needed to fit a certain quantity of smaller boxes.

[image: sample image]
[image: sample image]
[image: sample image]

How do i find the heights h2, h3, and h4.

w =  width of original rectangle
h1 = height of original rectangle

w and h1 is given say 300, 400
bh = small rectangles height
bw = small rectangles width

bh and bw is the same for all the rectangles and is given say 40, 40

sb = number of small boxes

three different sets are provided in this example, for each set the required height of the box needed to hold the small rectangles needs to be calculated

- for the first set which has sb as 6, I need to find h2
- for the second set which has sb as 7, I need to find h4
- for the third set which has sb as 8, I need to find h3

Comment: I don't understand completely. You probably don't mean just `h = bh * ceil(numberOfBoxes / floor(w / bw))`? Please clarify your problem. What are the inputs, what output do you expect?

Comment: i made some explanation, see if the edit helps

Comment: Why does the first row of small boxes not count into `sb`? How do you distinguish `h3` and `h4`, i.e. why is the last box not in the row before?

Comment: i have split the images, to make it more clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s still a bit unclear to me. But here is a try to answer your question.

The number of boxes that fit in a single row is:

```
boxesInRow = floor(w / bw)
```

In order to fit `n` boxes, you need the following count of rows:

```
rows = ceil(n / boxesInRow)
```

And the height of this big box is then just:

```
height = rows * bh
```

Now comes the part where I am not sure. You say that `sb` is the number of boxes. However, for the first image (h2), you say that `sb` should be 6, but I count 9 boxes. So apparently, you ignore the first row. If this is really the case, the final formula is:

```
height = bh * (rows + 1)
       = bh * (ceil(sb / floor(w / bw)) + 1)
```

Comment: Yes `sb` is 6 for the first box, because the big rectangle(container) is the black rectangle which has a height `h1`, now the question for the first picture is if 3 small boxes where added on top of the container as is the case, what would be the required new height `h2`, got it?

Comment: No, not really. What parameter stores the 3?